# While using X11 on a GPU, does XShmGetImage give you host/device memory back?

Tags: c++, linux, x11, nvidia, gnome

If you have X11 running on a GPU like so:

```
Fri Aug  2 23:52:39 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.30       Driver Version: 430.30       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla M60           Off  | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P8    14W / 150W |    141MiB /  7618MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      3255      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            57MiB |
|    0      3286      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          81MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you run XShmGetImage(), does it give you a pointer to a memory address in GPU memory or host memory?

If the GPU, I assume you can do other operations on the NVIDIA card with it, like H264 encode that data.

Is there a way to copy the memory from one GPU memory block to a different GPU memory block?

I am using NVENC libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [MIT Shared Memory extension's](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/Xext/mit-shm.html) documentation:

> The next step is to create the shared memory segment. This is best
> done after the creation of the XImage, since you need to make use of
> the information in that XImage to know how much memory to allocate. To
> create the segment, you need a call like:
>
> shminfo.shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, image->bytes_per_line * image->height, IPC_CREAT|0777);

This implies the extension regards "shared memory" as "that which is returned by `shmget` or equivalent". Since [`shmget` is incapable of allocating GPU memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html), *my answer is the XImage is in host memory*, not device.

Comment: Ouch, so it seems like X11 uses the GPU but those APIs create internal host memory buffers :(. I am wondering if you'd have to use low-level APIs like Direct Rendering Manager and talk to the kernel in order to get actual GPU memory of the frame that holds the image of the GUI.